# How to wait for the end of my animation to continue the code in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First of all i'm a beginner on the subject so maybe i missed something there, but i've tried everything i could find on the web but none of the solutions have worked for me. I wrote a code that triggers when a zombie collides with an object, then the zombie has an animation where it attack the object then deals damage to it. But in my case even if the object has a lot of lives the program don't stop for the end of animation to deal the damage. Here is my code :

```
    int damage = 1;

   public Animator animation1;


private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    Debug.Log("Collision!");
    GameObject triggered = other.gameObject;

    if (triggered.gameObject.tag == "obstacle")
    {
        do
        {

            animation1.Play("zombie_attack");
            triggered.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", damage);
            Debug.Log("damage taken");



        } while (triggered.GetComponent<ObjectHealth>().GetHealth() > 0);

    }

}
```

This script is attached to the zombie and the health script is attached to the object tagged as "obstacle". Has anyone an idea on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place an event at the end of the animation and call your "apply damage" code there. To do this bring up the animation window for your animation and right click the top bar. This will allow you create an event. Then select the event and choose a function to fire when it is reached. There  should be a dropdown in the inspector that lists all available functions. Functions are only available for the event if they are associated with a component that is attached to the selected game object (or attached to a child of that object), so make sure that you write your function in a script component that will be attached to the same game object as your animation.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but i managed to do what i wanted with an event like you pointed out. Thanks a lot !